# Could not download bundle at 'https://api.github.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, github, devops

Could not download bundle at 'https://api.github.com......' after 3 retries. Server returned codes: 404 'Not Found'; 404 'Not Found'; 404 'Not Found'; 404 'Not Found'.

In Codedeploy using Jenkins, I'm having this error
How can I solve this error?

Comment: Sounds like either the repo does not exist or your credentials don’t have access to the rep (is it private)

Comment: No, my repo exists and it's public 
But it's still showing the same error
@mokugo-devops